# DFS of a connected graph

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search

I am implementing DFS of graph. Here is my code:

```
// sv is the starting node for traversal
// edges is the adjacency matrix 
// n is the number of vertices
// visited is boolean vector to keep track of the visited nodes
void printdfs(vector<vector <int>> edges, int n, int sv, vector<bool> visited){
    
    cout<<sv<<"\t";
    visited[sv] = true;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(i == sv){
            continue;
        }
        if(edges[sv][i] == 1){
            if(visited[i] == true){
                continue; 
            }                       
            printdfs(edges, n, i, visited);
        }       
    }
}
```

[image: Graph-image]

I even did dry-running of the code several times but I am not able to identify what is going wrong, I am not getting the expected output and it is printing the already visited nodes again and again. Can someone please point out the mistake.

Comment: You are passing `visited` by value instead of by reference, so every recursive call uses a different copy.  Use `vector<bool>& visited` to avoid this.

Comment: Ohh yes what a silly thing to do. Thank you!